# messy/overwritten numbering in enumerate tag

Tags: listings, lists, enumerate

I have the following in my LateX code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
     \item
       \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(4, 9)]                                                                                                                                         
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
```

Now, the result I get overlaps/overwrites positions for the numberings:
[image: Very Messy Result]

This obviously, not what anyone would want to do. How can I fix the numbering?

Thanks for all the help?

Comment: Depending on your application, I would consider using `\lstinline` instead... Might I ask what you're trying to get at?  (Just out of curiosity.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave a blank line (or use `\par`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
     \item
       \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(4, 9)]                                                                                                                                         
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
\end{lstlisting}
\par
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}                                                                                                                                                      
          x = [x for x in xrange(6)]                                                                                                                                            
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use `\lstinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
     \item
       \lstinline{x = [x for x in xrange(4, 9)]}
      \item
       \lstinline{x = [x for x in xrange(6)]}
      \item
       \lstinline{x = [x for x in xrange(6)]}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a TeX command line where I could use a help interface? For example, could I do help(par)?

Comment: @codeking You can use the command `texdoc` but that is mostly for packages.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus there's `\show` that gives the "definition" of commands, but since `\par` is a TeX primitive, it won't help here. `\par` end the paragraph; it is equivalent to leaving a blank line in the code.